# merging two xml files and appending elements for similar elements and moving elements that aren't present in one file in python

Tags: python, xml, python-3.x, lxml, xml.etree

I want to merge two XML files. I read many solutions but they are specific to those files. I am using `xml.etree.ElementTree` as well as `lxml` for parsing, comparing the files, getting the differences. I understand my next step is:

```python
for element in file2.xml:
    if element present in file1.xml:
        append to output_file.xml
    else:
        copy element to the output_file
```

but I haven't worked much on XML, and the tools to merge are licensed, so I need to write a generic script to merge to the format I want.

#### `file1.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<great_grands>

    <great_grandpa_name_one>great_grandpa_name</great_grandpa_name_one>

    <grandpa>
        <grandpa_name>grandpa_name_one_1</grandpa_name>
    </grandpa>
    <grandpa>
        <grandpa_name>grandpa_name_two_1</grandpa_name>
    </grandpa>

    <grandma>
        <grandma_name>grandma_name_one_1</grandma_name>
    </grandma>
    <grandma>
        <grandma_name>grandma_name_two_1</grandma_name>
    </grandma>

</great_grands>
```

#### `file2.xml`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<great_grands>

    <great_grandpa_name_two>great_grandpa_name</great_grandpa_name_two>


    <grandpa>
        <grandpa_name_2>grandpa_name_one_2</grandpa_name_2>
    </grandpa>

    <grandma>
        <grandma_name_2>grandma_name_one_2</grandma_name_2>
    </grandma>

</great_grands>
```

#### Required output:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<great_grands>

    <great_grandpa_name_one>great_grandpa_name</great_grandpa_name_one>
    <great_grandma_name_two>great_grandma_name</great_grandma_name_two>

    <grandpa>
        <grandpa_name>grandpa_name_one_1</grandpa_name>
    </grandpa>
    <grandpa>
        <grandpa_name>grandpa_name_two_1</grandpa_name>
    </grandpa>

    <grandpa>
        <grandpa_name_2>grandpa_name_one_2</grandpa_name_2>
    </grandpa>

    <grandma>
        <grandma_name>grandma_name_one_1</grandma_name>
    </grandma>
    <grandma>
        <grandma_name>grandma_name_two_1</grandma_name>
    </grandma>

    <grandma>
        <grandma_name_2>grandma_name_one_2</grandma_name_2>
    </grandma>

</great_grands>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose declarative language and sibling to XPath, designed to transform XML files. Using its `document()` function, it can parse from external XML files at relative links. Python's `lxml` module can process XSLT 1.0 scripts.

And because XSLT scripts are well-formed XML files you can parse from file or embedded string. Below assumes all files and scripts are saved in same directory:

**XSLT** Script *(save as .xsl script, notice only file2.xml is referenced)*

```
<xsl:transform xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="/great_grands">
   <xsl:copy>
     <xsl:copy-of select="great_grandpa_name_one"/>
     <xsl:copy-of select="document('file2.xml')/great_grands/great_grandpa_name_two"/>
     <xsl:copy-of select="grandpa"/>
     <xsl:copy-of select="document('file2.xml')/great_grands/grandpa"/>
     <xsl:copy-of select="grandma"/>
     <xsl:copy-of select="document('file2.xml')/great_grands/grandma"/>
   </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

**Python** Script  *(notice only file1.xml is referenced)*

```
from lxml import etree

xml = etree.parse('file1.xml')
xsl = etree.parse('XSLTScript.xsl')

transform = etree.XSLT(xsl)
newdom = transform(xml)

# SAVE NEW DOM STRING TO FILE
with open('Output.xml', 'wb') as f:
   f.write(newdom)
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<great_grands>
  <great_grandpa_name_one>great_grandpa_name</great_grandpa_name_one>
  <great_grandpa_name_two>great_grandpa_name</great_grandpa_name_two>
  <grandpa>
    <grandpa_name>grandpa_name_one_1</grandpa_name>
  </grandpa>
  <grandpa>
    <grandpa_name>grandpa_name_two_1</grandpa_name>
  </grandpa>
  <grandpa>
    <grandpa_name_2>grandpa_name_one_2</grandpa_name_2>
  </grandpa>
  <grandma>
    <grandma_name>grandma_name_one_1</grandma_name>
  </grandma>
  <grandma>
    <grandma_name>grandma_name_two_1</grandma_name>
  </grandma>
  <grandma>
    <grandma_name_2>grandma_name_one_2</grandma_name_2>
  </grandma>
</great_grands>
```

Comment: Sorry if this sounds ridiculous but the 'XSLTScript.xsl' - should I manually write it or python can help me do it ?

Comment: You can do either. XSLT is a well-formed XML file, so you can parse it from file like any other XML or parse from string. I'll save it with your source files and in case you need XSLT outside Python, you can do so.

Comment: Is there any lingering issues?

Comment: I need to know how to convert a.xml file to a.xsl using just python. Thank you

Comment: No one converts xml to xsl. Sorry for that confusion. XSLT is a script file to convert one xml to another xml, or html, or text. As analogy, you never convert .csv data to a .py script.

Comment: Did you run this solution? What is the problem/error?

Comment: I have many lengthy xml files, I can use a merging tool but that would again take time at places, so I was wondering if I could automate it. And the above code works for the example here, but making those lengthy xml files to xsl manually would again take more time.

Comment: I still do not understand your process. XSLT only needs to be written once and then have Python loop through XML files iteratively transforming with this same script to final XML. Are you saying you have more XML needing to be merged to extend the `document()` calls in XSLT?